# Обрезка строки в mysql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы в строке после запроса удалялось всё после пробела? 
Прим. "аааа ббб"--> "аааа"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сегодня прямо ночь mysql-извращений, отягощённых нежеланием читать документацию...

```
SELECT IF
(
  LOCATE(' ',`field`)=0, 
  `field`, 
  LEFT(`field`,LOCATE(' ',`field`))
) 
FROM `table`
```